# nvarchar(max) field is empty when I insert ~81192 characters in it on SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

When i try to insert a new record in to one column named `ProductDetail( nvarchar(MAX))`. I inserted with value ~81192 characters. Then that column got empty. I inserted with small value then it inserted OK? How can i fix this issue?

```
FakeDtbDataContext dt=new FakeDtbDataContext();
...

string sql = "Insert Into SanPham(IDNhomSP,ChiTiet) Values('" + prDetail + "','" + FCK.Value + "')";
dt.ExecuteCommand(sql);
```

**SQL Version is 10.50.1600.**

I debugged and it has value. I run script with remote SQL Server.

I've inserted using LinQ statement, LinQ itself may prevent injection. The column still get empty :(

```
var sanPham = new SanPham
{
     IDNhomSP = nhomhang,
     ChiTiet = FCK.Value
};
dt.SanPhams.InsertOnSubmit(sanPham);
dt.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: 1) Did you debugged and checked that before running the insert prDetail variable has any value? 2) Have you run a SQL trace to check the sql statement actually executed?

Comment: I agree: run a SQL trace - but also; do you have any triggers that might be playing up?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the solution, but always use paramtereized queryies! If either `prDetail`, or `FCK.Value` contains an apostrophe, your sql code breaks, and worse, your code is open for [SQL injection :)](http://xkcd.com/327/)!

Something like this:

```
string sql = "Insert Into SanPham(IDNhomSP,ChiTiet) Values(@prDetail, @FCKValue)";
```

And add the value of your prDetail and FCK.Value as parameters to the command before executing.

Answer (score 0):

How do you see that the column is empty?

**SSMS Edit rows does not show too long strings, but Select will...**

If you are ure the value is empty, could you specify what code generation you use for Entity Framework (if you dont use the default one), if you use Code First, and make sure that the SSDL is

```
<Property Name="ChiTiet" Type="nvarchar(max)" />
```

and not

```
<Property Name="ChiTiet" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="max" />
```

Comment: I'm using LinQ to SQL (dbml), and i checked value in this column, it's empty